# Подтверждение отправки при обновлении

Tags: php, firefox

Как сделать, чтобы при обновлений страницы не запрашивал подтверждение отправки данных?

Делаю форму авторизации через php. Вот форма:

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
     <form method="post" action="{{where_to_link}}">
     <table border="0" align="center" style="border:none;" class="login" id="logintable">

    <tbody><tr><td><a href="{{where_to_link}}"><img alt="" src="img/success.png" /></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Логин:</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="user" title="Enter your Username" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Пароль:</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="password" name="pass" title="Enter your password" /></td></tr>

     <tr><td><p><input type="submit" value="Войти" name="login" /></p></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
     </form>
{% include 'footer.html'  %}
```

Авторизуюсь, потом когда просто обновляю страницу, то браузер(Firefox) как бы все время запрашивает подтверждение отправки данных. Как сделать, чтобы 1 раз авторизовался - и все, никогда больше не запрашивал подтверждение при обновлений страницы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

на эту же страницу